# Run a file.py in django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project, in which I have already defined the models.

I write a file called my_logic.py, which contains custom logics for my app; for example, it SQL-ly queries the relevant data from the database, formats that data, and sends them to an online ML-model to get prediction.

I would like to automatically run this file every hour. Is there any way to achieve this? I think the possible answer is cronjob.

Thanks

Comment: a cron job is the most obvious answer. But if you are looking for something that is scalable [Check this out - django-rq](https://github.com/rq/django-rq)

Comment: Thanks @vvk24. I will try it